# Struts 2 <s:property evaluate express

Tags: struts2

I am trying to evaluate expression in `<s:property` tag as following..

i am able to print `<s:property value="%{quoted*100)}>`

but unable to print following expression

```
<s:property value="%{quoted*100)/Total}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`<s:property value="%{(quoted*100)/Total}" />` missing '('